# ext4 Data Recovery from format

Tags: ext4, data-loss

When doing a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 I accidentally selected for my data disk.  I have already searched for the partition using testdisk and couldn't find the data partition.

Files on the disk were video and audio files.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid if you have written over your data disk it is unlikely that you will be able to recover your lost data. There is a wealth of knowledge about [data recovery here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery).

Comment: i haven't written with testdisk, just went up to list files and it didn't list any files in the partitions that it had found.